# What is the most efficient method to compute recuversively (sparse) matrix power?

Tags: matrices, exponentiation, computational-complexity, sparse-matrices

I have a sparse matrix $P$ and I want to take its $n$-th power.

more precisely my problem is "is it better to make

```
for k=1:n
   result(k)=result(k-1)+P^k;
end
```

or

```
temp=eye(size(P))
for k=1:n
   temp=temp*P
   result(k)=result(k-1)+temp;
end
```

?". The two methods should give the same results.  If yes, then why?

(Note that I am not finding for the most efficient way to compute a sparse matrix but just to compare the two methods).

Comment: More efficient in which sense ? Less operations ? How do you "just make" $P^n$ directly ?

Comment: More efficient in the computational time point of view. I mean $P^n$ with a language function (I use $^$ of Matlab)

Comment: According to Matlab documentation, $P^n$ is computed by repeated squaring when $n$ is a positive integer. So it will be more efficient then your function. For example to compute $P^{16}$, it would compute $P^2$ then $P^2P^2=Q$ then $Q^2$ and finally $Q^2Q^2=P^{16}$. So only 4 matrices multiplications instead of ... 15.

Comment: Matlab probably uses binary exponentiation (at least I would hope so), so only $O(\log(n))$ matrix multiplications are used, unlike $n$ in your code.

Comment: And if you really have a diagonal matrix then probably it will detect that too.

Comment: @nicomezi I have edited my question, could you please look at my request (slightly different from before)

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I have edited my question, could you please look at my request (slightly different from before)

Comment: Have you tried to experiment with it?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $P\in M_m$, $P$ has $km$ non zero entries (with $k/m$ small) and  you want to calculate $I+P+\cdots +P^n$ (clearly both methods give the previous result when $result(0)=I_m$). Assume also that $n$ is a large number; the fact that $P^i$ is sparse or is not sparse, for $i<n$ large enough, depends on the choice of non-zero entries.

For example, if $P$ is a band matrix, then the $P^i$ 's quickly become non-sparse.

Another example: for $m=100,k=2$, in general, $P^{10}$ is non-sparse.

In the sequel, we assume that the $(P^i)$ are non-sparse. The complexity of the first method is

$\sim\sum_{i=1}^n \log(i)m^3\sim n\log(n)m^3$.

The complexity of the second method is $\sim nm^2k$ (each step has complexity $m^2k$ for $i$ large enough).

Then the best method is the second one.

Comment: Any references for the time complexity you mention?

Comment: @Blue , it's standard: we can calculate $P^l$ (for any $P$) with at most $2\log_2(l)$ matricial multiplications (write $l$ in $2$-basis), that gives a complexity   $O(m^3\log(l))$. If $P$ is sparse, then $PP^{l-1}$ can be calculated with exactly $m^2k$ multiplications of numbers; thus $P,\cdots,P^l$ can be calculated with $lm^2k$ mult.